# Why does calling AutoFake.Provide() wipe out fakes already configured with A.CallTo()?

Tags: autofac, fakeiteasy

Why does calling `fake.Provide<T>()` wipe out fakes already configured with `A.CallTo()`? Is this a bug?

I'm trying to understand a problem I've run into with [Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy) (aka AutoFake).  I have a partial solution, but I don't understand why my original code doesn't work. The original code is complicated, so I've spent some time simplifying it for the purposes of this question.

Why does this test fail? ([working DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5vl1m9))

```cs
public interface IStringService { string GetString(); }

public static void ACallTo_before_Provide()
{
    using (var fake = new AutoFake())
    {
        A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IStringService>().GetString())
            .Returns("Test string");

        fake.Provide(new StringBuilder());
        
        var stringService = fake.Resolve<IStringService>();
        string result = stringService.GetString();

        // FAILS. The result should be "Test string",
        // but instead it's an empty string.
        Console.WriteLine($"ACallTo_before_Provide(): result = \"{result}\"");
    }
}
```

If I swap the order of the calls to `fake.Provide<T>()` and `A.CallTo()`, it works:

```cs
public static void Provide_before_ACallTo()
{
    // Same code as above, but with the calls to
    // fake.Provide<T>() and A.CallTo() swapped
    using (var fake = new AutoFake())
    {
        fake.Provide(new StringBuilder());
        
        A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IStringService>().GetString())
            .Returns("Test string");
        
        var stringService = fake.Resolve<IStringService>();
        string result = stringService.GetString();

        // SUCCESS. The result is "Test string" as expected
        Console.WriteLine($"Provide_before_ACallTo(): result = \"{result}\"");
    }
}
```

I know what is happening, sort of, but I'm not sure if it's intentional behavior or if it's a bug.

What is happening is, the call to `fake.Provide<T>()` is causing anything configured with `A.CallTo()` to be lost. As long as I always call `A.CallTo()` **after** `fake.Provide<T>()`, everything works fine.

But I don't understand why this should be.

- I can't find anything in [the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/fakeiteasy.html) stating that `A.CallTo()` cannot be called before `Provide<T>()`.
- Likewise, I can't find anything suggesting `Provide<T>()` cannot be used with `A.CallTo()`.

It seems the order in which you configure unrelated dependencies shouldn't matter.

Is this a bug? Or is this the expected behavior? If this is the expected behavior, can someone explain why it works like this?

Comment: It appears this is indeed a bug; an issue has been opened for it [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy/issues/22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that the Fake's configuration is being changed. In the first test, `Resolve` is returning different Fakes each time it's called. (Check them for reference equality; I did.)

`Provide` creates a new [scope](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/) and pushes it on a stack. The topmost scope is used by `Resolve` when it finds an object to return. I think this is why you're getting different Fakes in `ACallTo_before_Provide`.

> Is this a bug? Or is this the expected behavior? If this is the expected behavior, can someone explain why it works like this?

It's not clear to me. I'm not an Autofac user, and don't understand why an additional scope is introduced by `Provide`. The stacked scope behaviour was introduced in [PR 18](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy/pull/18). Perhaps the author can explain why.

In the meantime, if possible, I'd `Provide` all you need to before `Resolve`ing, if you can manage it.

Comment: It appears it is a bug; I've opened an issue for it [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy/issues/22). In the meantime, I'll try to order my `Provide` calls to come before `Resolve`ing as you suggest.